# Accented characters using JavaFX on Linux

Tags: linux, javafx-2, javafx

I'm developing an application and just noticed that not a single accented character, for example, the Brazilian Portuguese "é", neither "ã" are displayed when I'm running the JavaFX application on Linux.

BUT, if I copy/paste those characters they appear normally, so I don't think it's an encoding problem.

On the other hand, the exactly same code works on Windows and those characters are displayed normally.

Is this a known bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a simple example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @assylias Well, it doesn't involve code but if, in my application, I try to type "é" (´ + e), the textfield will displaye "e". But if I type "é" in gedit, for example, and copy/paste it in the same textfield, it will appear as it should ("é").

Comment: Does it work in [jdk8](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html)?  If not, [log a bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) with detailed environment and reproduction steps.

Comment: @jewelsea Will try it!

Comment: @jewelsea Didn't work :(. I'll log a bug as you said. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem in a project which a team member was using Eclipse on Windows, with default encoding to ISO-8859-1, while I was using UTF-8 on Linux.

So, if you're using Eclipse, check your encoding at `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace`, then `Text file encoding` group.